# Typecast generic type C++

Tags: c++, generics, casting

I overloaded the `operator[]` for my `DataStructure` class to return the indicated value, as follows:

```
T& operator[](int i) {
    return m_array[i];
}
```

But when I loop over the values, I want to print them as follows:

```
for (int i = 0, s = stack->size(); i < s; ++i) {
    printf("%7i %5i\n", i, stack[i]);
}
```

Since I created the generic DataStructure as an integer Stack (derived class)

```
stack = new Stack<int>(STACKSIZE);
```

But this does not work. I expected every item on the stack to be int, but the compiler says I cannot typecast `Stack<int>` to `int`, even though I'm not trying to typecast an Stack!!!

What am I missing? Also, I can not use

```
printf("%7i %5i\n", i, (int)stack[i]);
```

Since for some reason it "is not" an integer type.

Comment: Can you post a [minimal example that lets us see the error for ourselves](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Your `operator[]` function uses a member named `m_array`. In the `printf` statement, you are using `stack[i]`, which appears to be an array of `Stack` objects. Obvisously, `stack[i]` evaluates to a `Stack` object. What's the relationship between `m_array` and `stack`?

Comment: Are you coming from Java? You'll want to use `new` a lot less in C++ than you would in Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `stack` is a pointer to a `Stack<int>`, then `stack[i]` doesn't call the stack's `operator[]`. It treats the pointer as a pointer to the first element of an array and tries to index into that array. Either don't make it a pointer:

```
Stack<int> stack(STACKSIZE);
```

or dereference the pointer:

```
(*stack)[i]
```

Comment: When I tried the first option, more things broken. However, the second option works. Thanks for the explanation on why it wasn't working.